# How do I dial the PSTN with Asterisk?

Tags: sip, asterisk, twilio, webrtc, tropo

I am playing around with WebRTC and would like to dial a real landline from my web browser by connecting through Asterisk.  I've followed this tutorial http://nerdvittles.com/?p=5321  for connecting to asterisk through WebRTC, but I don't know how to set Asterisk up to dial a real telephone.  Is this something that I could do with Twilio, or Tropo?   Or do I need another service?   I would like to be able to dial numbers in Europe (France) and the United States

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need integrate your Asterisk with a VOIP provider service or install a hardware interface like FXO or E1!

After you need configure your dialplan to the output of the calls (this can be specific to what kind of solution you choose).

Answer (score 0):

You could use sip trunk from one of the neighbor provider. You should use sip.conf for that. 
or
You can install some hardware as ederwander.

Also you should use extension.conf to configure dialplan.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

This is indeed something you can do with Twilio using our [Twilio Client for JavaScript SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/client) which uses WebRTC in browsers that support it (but will fall back to Flash for others).

Client lets you make audio connects between your browser and Twilio.  Once connected you can direct Twilio to dial a PSTN number and bridge it to the Client connection.

Check out this [quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/client/outgoing-calls), which demonstrates making calls from a browser to either another browser or a PSTN number.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is this new?  I ended up going with phono.js from tropo..  is this something similar?

Comment: Twilio Client has been available for a couple of years now.  Its available in a JavaScript SDK for browser apps, and iOS and Android SDK's for native mobile applications.  Hope that helps.